# is There any function in opencv which is equivalent to matlab conv2

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv, convolution

Is there any direct opencv function for matlab function conv2? I tried using cvFilter2D(), but it seems to be giving me different results than conv2().

For example:

```
CvMat * Aa = cvCreateMat(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
CvMat * Bb = cvCreateMat(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
CvMat * Cc = cvCreateMat(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
cvSetReal2D(Aa, 0, 0, 1);
cvSetReal2D(Aa, 0, 1, 2);
cvSetReal2D(Aa, 1, 0, 3);
cvSetReal2D(Aa, 1, 1, 4);
cvSetReal2D(Bb, 0, 0, 5);
cvSetReal2D(Bb, 0, 1, 5);
cvSetReal2D(Bb, 1, 0, 5);
cvSetReal2D(Bb, 1, 1, 5);
cvFilter2D(Aa, Cc, Bb);

This produces the matrix [20 30; 40 50]


In MATLAB:
>> A=[1 2; 3 4]
A =
1 2
3 4

>> B=[5 5; 5 5]
B =
5 5
5 5

>> conv2(A,B,'shape')
ans =
50 30
35 20
```

Please Help me.its very much useful for me.Thank you.

Regards

Arangarajan.

Comment: minor edit: the correct call is `conv2(A,B,'same')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using convolution, there is problem at the edge of the matrix. The convolution mask needs values which are outside of the matrix. The algorithms from OpenCV and matlab use different strategies to cope with this problem. OpenCV just replicates the pixels of the border whereas matlab just assumes that all this pixels are zero.

So if you want to emulate the behaviour of matlab in OpenCV you can add this zero padding manually. There even is a dedicated function for this. Let me give you an example of how your code could be modified:

```
CvMat * Ccb = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
CvMat * Aab = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
cvCopyMakeBorder(Aa,Aab, cvPoint(0,0),IPL_BORDER_CONSTANT, cvScalarAll(0));
cvFilter2D(Aab, Ccb, Bb);
```

The result this gives is:

```
20.000   30.000   20.000 
40.000   50.000   30.000 
30.000   35.000   20.000
```

To get your intended result you just need to delete the first column and row to get rid of the additional data introduced by the border we added.

Comment: +1 keep in mind that the function `cvFilter2D` performs correlation while `conv2` does convolution. For the example above this wouldn't matter, but if the kernel was not symmetric you need to rotate it by 180 degrees for the results to match.

Answer (score 9):

The numerical computing environment Matlab (or e.g. its free alternative GNU Octave) provides a function called conv2 for the two-dimensional convolution of a given matrix with a convolution kernel. While writing some C++ code based upon the free image processing library OpenCV, I found that OpenCV currently offers no equivalent method.

Although there is a filter2D() method that implements two-dimensional correlation and that can be used to convolute an image with a given kernel (by flipping that kernel and moving the anchor point to the correct position, as explained on the corresponding OpenCV documentation page), it would be nice to have a method offering the same border handling options as Matlab (“full”, “valid” or “same” convolution), e.g. for comparing results of the same algorithm implemented in both Matlab and C++ using OpenCV.

Here is what I came up with:

```
enum ConvolutionType {   
/* Return the full convolution, including border */
  CONVOLUTION_FULL, 

/* Return only the part that corresponds to the original image */
  CONVOLUTION_SAME,

/* Return only the submatrix containing elements that were not influenced by the border       
*/
  CONVOLUTION_VALID
};

void conv2(const Mat &img, const Mat& kernel, ConvolutionType type, Mat& dest) {
  Mat source = img;
  if(CONVOLUTION_FULL == type) {
    source = Mat();
    const int additionalRows = kernel.rows-1, additionalCols = kernel.cols-1;
    copyMakeBorder(img, source, (additionalRows+1)/2, additionalRows/2,     
(additionalCols+1)/2, additionalCols/2, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
  }

  Point anchor(kernel.cols - kernel.cols/2 - 1, kernel.rows - kernel.rows/2 - 1);
  int borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT;
  filter2D(source, dest, img.depth(), flip(kernel), anchor, 0, borderMode);

  if(CONVOLUTION_VALID == type) {
    dest = dest.colRange((kernel.cols-1)/2, dest.cols - kernel.cols/2)
           .rowRange((kernel.rows-1)/2, dest.rows - kernel.rows/2);
  }
}
```

In my unit tests, this implementation yielded results that were almost identical with the Matlab implementation. Note that both OpenCV and Matlab do the convolution in Fourier space if the kernel is large enough. The definition of ‘large’ varies in both implementations, but results should still be very similar, even for large kernels.

Also, the performance of this method might be an issue for the ‘full’ convolution case, since the entire source matrix needs to be copied to add a border around it. Finally, If you receive an exception in the filter2D() call and you are using a kernel with only one column, this might be caused by this bug. In that case, set the borderMode variable to e.g. BORDER_REPLICATE instead, or use the latest version of the library from the OpenCV trunk.

Comment: +1 Best answer so far. Code snippet is good and perform something very similar to MATLAB's `conv2`. Plus it is a good thing to remind that OpenCV's `filter2D` performs correlation and not convolution.

Comment: Shouldn't the flip() take at least two parameters ? According to doc C++: void flip(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int flipCode) . Therefore it should be cv::flip(kernel,kernel, 0)