# Conv2 in opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm working on image processing and need to know an equivalent of conv2 of Matlab in c++ OpenCV.
I  found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309561/is-there-any-function-in-opencv-which-is-equivalent-to-matlab-conv2/12540358), but it doesn't suit my requirements.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to convolute a Mat image with a 2-D double array, which is not the case given in the link above.

The matlab code is:

```
img = conv2(img1,Mx,'same')
```

where

```
Mx = {  
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} ,   
  {0, -0.0003, -0.0035, 0, 0.0035, 0.0003} ,   
  {0, -0.0090, -0.0903, 0, 0.0903, 0.0090} , 
  {0, -0.0229, -0.2292, 0, 0.2292, 0.0229} ,   
  {0, -0.0090, -0.0903, 0, 0.0903, 0.0090} ,   
  {0, -0.0003, -0.0035, 0, 0.0035, 0.0003}  
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution**

Use OpenCV's [filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20filter2D(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType)) function.

**Code example**

```
//initializes matrix
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::ones(50, 50, CV_32F); 

//initializes kernel
float  Mx[36] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,
     0, -0.0003, -0.0035, 0, 0.0035, 0.0003  ,
     0, -0.0090, -0.0903, 0, 0.0903, 0.0090  ,
     0, -0.0229, -0.2292, 0, 0.2292, 0.0229  ,
     0, -0.0090, -0.0903, 0, 0.0903, 0.0090  ,
     0, -0.0003, -0.0035, 0, 0.0035, 0.0003 
};
cv::Mat kernel(6, 6, CV_32F, Mx);

//convolove
cv::Mat dst;
cv::filter2D(mat, dst, mat.depth(), kernel);
```

Comment: But i heard , Filter2D does correlation ,not convolution ?

Comment: no, from OpenCV documentation: "filter2D - Convolves an image with the kernel."

Comment: But in the same documentation , it is given as : "The function does actually compute correlation, not the convolution: That is, the kernel is not mirrored around the anchor point. If you need a real convolution, flip the kernel using flip() and set the new anchor to (kernel.cols - anchor.x - 1, kernel.rows - anchor.y - 1) ."                                                                                               
                                                                                                              
 What about that ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my attempt, I'm not sure whether it's accurate, but for very small amount of test data, it worked for me:

```
enum Conv2DShape {
    FULL,
    SAME,
    VALID,
};

Mat conv2D( const Mat& input, const Mat& kernel, const Conv2DShape shape ){
    Mat flipped_kernel;
    flip( kernel, flipped_kernel, -1 );

    Point2i pad;
    Mat result, padded;

    switch( shape ) {
        case SAME:
            padded = input;
            pad = Point2i( 0, 0 );
            break;

        case VALID:
            padded = input;
            pad = Point2i( kernel.cols - 1, kernel.rows - 1);
            break;

        case FULL:
            pad = Point2i( kernel.cols - 1, kernel.rows - 1);
            copyMakeBorder( input, padded, pad.y, pad.y, pad.x, pad.x, BORDER_CONSTANT );
            break;

        default:
            throw runtime_error("Unsupported convolutional shape");
    }

    Rect region = Rect( pad.x / 2, pad.y / 2, padded.cols - pad.x, padded.rows - pad.y);
    filter2D( padded, result , -1, flipped_kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_CONSTANT );

    return result( region );
}
```